# После выполнения запроса содержание переменной изменяется (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

ребята! Просьба помочь в решении задачи. Раньше все работало хорошо, на днях что-то пошло не так.
Проверьте пожалуйста на ошибки процедуру:

```
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
SET @taskId := 0;
Select @taskId := tasks.id, products.id, products.asin
From tasks
Inner Join products
ON products.id = tasks.product_id
Where tasks.`status` = "waiting"
Order by tasks.created_at asc 
Limit 1
FOR UPDATE;
-- select @taskId;
UPDATE tasks SET `status`="processing", started_at = NOW() WHERE id=@taskId;
COMMIT;
END
```

Выполняем процедуру из запроса:

```
call get_task();
```

Проверяем статус таски

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE `status` = "processing";
```

***Question:***
почему в результате первой части запроса у нас результате таска 844394, а в результате второй части таска другая 845280

http://prntscr.com/n1uc0u

http://prntscr.com/n1ud5j

Подробное описание траблы если был не до конца красноречив в тексте: https://youtu.be/c-_G7akyk8M

Comment: Это конечно дико странно. Но замечу, что в процедурах принято использовать процедурные переменные, объявляемые через declare (без собак). И получение значений в них через select into

Answer (score 0):

Правильный ответ такой:

```
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;

set @taskId := 0;

select @taskId := tasksId, id, asin from
(Select tasks.id as tasksId, products.id, products.asin
From tasks
Inner Join products
ON products.id = tasks.product_id
Where tasks.`status` = "waiting"
Order by tasks.id asc 
Limit 1
for update) as table1;

select @taskId;
UPDATE tasks SET `status`="processing", started_at = NOW() WHERE id=@taskId;

COMMIT;
END
```

Но я не знаю почему он таки сработал )) Кто подскажет будет интересно почитать ))